# Here Map API Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'immediateRedraw' of null

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api, angular10, heremaps

We have upgraded the project Angular version 7 to angular version 10, but on **Here Map API** not working on below

> 1. The first Angular component is working fine
> 2. When we change or select another component Here map is not rendering getting below error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'immediateRedraw' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'immediateRedraw' of null
at mapsjs-core.js:418
at l.invoke (polyfills.572d73b94f023dc97cfc.js:1)
```

How to fix the Here Map issue?

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually due to the map div not rendered correctly.

Comment: We've the same situation with angular and here-maps api. The map is rendered normally in the container-div. We're working with the map: adding markers, zooming, etc. and if we leave the current component by navigating to another route (component). We call the dispose-methods:
```
    this.mapBehavior?.dispose();
    this.mapEvents?.dispose();
    this.map?.dispose();

    this.mapBehavior = null;
    this.mapEvents = null;
    this.map = null;
```
Right after the call to map.dispose() the Error is thrown. If we comment out the line map.dispose() the error isn't thrown. map is H:map